# Typescript & Jquery: what is the best practice to call a class into Jquery onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I don't want instantiate a class in each function. How to? 
What should be the best practice to organize this in a Typescript syntax?

```
$(".container_dettaglio .varianti .variante a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var pr = new Prodotto($(this).data('variante'));
    pr.cambiaVariante();
});

$(".meno").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pr = new Prodotto($(this).data('variante'));
    pr.rimuoviQuantita();
});

$(".piu").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pr = new Prodotto($(this).data('variante'));
    pr.aggiungiQuantita();
});
```

Comment: Presumably the `data-variante` will be different for each element? So you either need to restructure the `Produtto` object to read from a property which you amend, or keep the current pattern of instantiating a new class for each value being set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best workaround (I think) you can do is to restructure your class to return functions which will do your desires. This is an example of what I mean:

```
var MyClass = function(){
    return {
        Set: function(a, b, c){
            return [a, b, c].toString();
        },

        Modify: function(a){
            return a + ' .)';
        }
    }
};

$(function(){
    var mc = new MyClass();

    $('.a').on('click', function(){
        alert( mc.Modify($(this).data('variant')) );
    });

    $('.b').on('click', function(){
        alert( mc.Modify($(this).data('variant')) );
    });

});
```

So, by this way you instantiate your class once. [Check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/8mp7o1h4/)